# Stanford CoreNLP - Test command with conll output

Tags: python, parsing, dependencies, stanford-nlp

I'm new with CoreNLP and Dependency Parser. I'm a bit lost with the documentation. In this doc page I found how to train a model [train doc page](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/nndep.shtml) but I can't find the command line to test a file in conll format with a pre-trained model and get the ouput in conll. Someone knows the command?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the command here [Dependency Javadoc](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp-3.5.0/edu/stanford/nlp/parser/nndep/DependencyParser.html) so If someone needs know the test command to test a conll file with a trained model and set the output in conll format use this command:

-> Change "-mx10g" to the ammount of RAM that you need <-

`java -mx10g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser -model /path/to/<your.model.txt or your.model.txt.gz> -testFile /path/to/conllu/test/file/en-ud-test.conllu -outFile results.conll`